# Почему не пингуется домен в локальной сети на Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, сеть, active-directory, windows-server-2012

windows server 2012 поднял Active Directory и создал домен avk.local
Полное имя компьютера стало server.avk.local
ip компьютера 192.168.137.91

Клиентской машине (под управлением Windows 7) прописал DNS 192.168.137.91
сделал ping avk.local (передача пакетов успешно проходила)

Но когда зашел на ubuntu и ввел ping avk.local, то он не нашел домен (компьютер под управлением Ubuntu заходит в сеть с wi-fi, но в параметрах сети DNS установлен 192.168.137.91)

Что я делаю не так?

Единственное, если запускать на Ubuntu (то тут видно ведь, но почему не пингует):

```
$ nslookup server
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Name:   server.avk.local
Address: 192.168.137.91
```

Работает и сам пинг на компьютер сервера:

```
$ ping server
PING server.avk.local (192.168.137.91) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.137.91: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.01 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.137.91: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=3.42 ms
```

Но как на клиентской машине (под управлением Windows) не работает

```
$ ping server.avk.local
ping: unknown host server.avk.local
$ ping avk.local
ping: unknown host avk.local
```

Comment: Потому что на убунте скорее всего работает `avahi`. Почитай про https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroconf. Я бы на твоём месте `local` поменял на `work`, `home` или типа того.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открываем файл /etc/nsswitch.conf и ищем в нем строчку, отвечающую за хосты.
В openSUSE 11.3 она выглядит так:

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

В Ubuntu 10.04 она выглядит так:

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

Все что нам надо сделать, это избавиться от опции [NOTFOUND=return], приведя строчку к виду:

- openSUSE 11.3

  ```
  hosts: files mdns4_minimal dns
  ```
- Ubuntu 10.04

  ```
  hosts: files mdns4_minimal dns mdns4
  ```

Перезапускаем avahi-daemon.

https://habrahabr.ru/post/103009/